# How can I update my table after X minutes?

Tags: php, mysql, events, zend-framework, stored-procedures

How I can update my table after X minute from my action

I send this request:

```
$req = Query("UPDATE clients SET lockclient = 0 WHERE id = $id")
```

And I want create the event after 5 min.

```
UPDATE clients SET lockclient = 1 WHERE id = $id
```

I tried to create the event with stored procedure , but this is imposible

```
DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE PROCEDURE proc
   (  
      idClient INTEGER 
   ) 
   BEGIN 
        CREATE EVENT updateClientLock
            ON SCHEDULE
                AT NOW() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
            ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
            ENABLE
        DO BEGIN
            UPDATE client set lockclient = 0 where id = idClient ;
        END

   END$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I just answer to [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29820729/3351765), I think it's the same problem. May be it can help you.

Comment: Thanks but i want to do it with php and my mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of the problem :

```
static public function eventUpdateLockClient($id, $min)
{
    $bdd = new mysqli ($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
    $sql1 = "CREATE EVENT updateClientLock$id
        ON SCHEDULE
        AT NOW() + INTERVAL $min MINUTE
        ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
        ENABLE
        DO BEGIN
            UPDATE clients set lockclient = 0 where id = $id ;
        END";
    $bdd->query(${"sql1"});

}
```

Comment: will this work on shared hosting? or you need vps for this?

Answer (score 3):

by using a cron job file for X mins you can do it
it will automatically call it after specified time given by you

Comment: Store it in a special table in your database